# Reverse string function in C

Tags: c, string, reverse

```
 void reverse_string( char * string )
 {
     // Insert your code here
     int i;
     int length = strlen(string); 
     char* temp; // string is a pointer, so temp must be a pointer as well.
          for(i=0; i<= length/2 ; i++)
          { 
            temp = *(string +i); 
            *(string +i) = *(string + length-(1*i));
            *(string + length-(1*i))= temp; 
          }
 }
```

Why is it that string, in the strlen function, does not require a '*' infront? I'm also getting an error for temp = *(string +i) but it works when i put char temp =... . I assumed that temp would work in the for loop without putting the type infront since i've already declared it in the reverse_string function but it doesn't.

Comment: You seem to be completely confused what a type is, what a value of a type is, and what operations on a value of a specific type return (type and value-wise). Anyway, shall that be C or C++? Please add one of the master-tags.

Comment: You need to understand what `*` means exactly first.

Comment: Start with any C tutorial/book. The [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) and the [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) are good starting points. BTW: This site is not for mentoring.

Comment: `strlen` takes an argument of type `char*`. It uses that pointer value to access the `char` elements of the array.

Comment: `1*i` will always equal `i`.

Comment: @Deduplicator- Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*ptr` is called dereferencing a pointer; it's equivalent to the value `ptr` points to.
In C we access strings by a pointer to the first character in that string. This is why strings are null terminated, because you really only know where the string starts in memory. You're simply passing your pointer to `strlen`, `*string` would be passing the first character in your string instead.

C also supports pointer arithmetic, where you can offset a pointer by adding or subtracting from it like you would an int. The result will be a pointer offset by the size of the type it points to multiplied by the number offset.`string + i` gives you a pointer to the i'th character after the one pointed to by `string`; thus `*(string + i)` is a character, not a pointer, since you're dereferencing a pointer to char. So, you don't want `temp` to be a pointer, so remove the * in its declaration.

Comment: @Trey They never claimed to have downvoted your answer.